# What is the Rails way of validating ends of a many-to-many relationship that must agree on a property?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have many Schools, many Students and many Clubs.
A student can go to one or more schools.
A school can have any number of clubs.

A student can be added to a club as long as they currently are enrolled in the school the club belongs to.

I would be tempted to do something like this in the ClubStudent join class

```
class ClubStudent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: student
  belongs_to: club

  validate: student_school_matches_club_school

  def student_school_matches_club_school
    unless student.schools.member? club.school
      self.errors.add(:student, "must be enrolled in club's school")
    end
  end
end
```

The problem, is based on the ordering of how things are created, or persisted, or if a student is added to a club or a club is added to a student, that validation could be run with a nil student or nil club. OR apparently it can fail validation but still be persisted.

What is the best way to deal with this type of validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently (as of Rails 3.2.13), Rails will save both ends of the the relation if they are not yet persisted before the validation is run.
So they won't be null and they will look persisted. 
Rails does this in a transaction, so if the validation fails, you won't end up with persisted objects.

In previous versions of Rails, the values being related could appear as nil in the relation's validation methods.

This makes coding validations much more straightforward as of 3.2.13. 
This seems like a major change for a 'TINY' version bump. Make sure related code is well tested.