# Has many association on tagging user in a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

In my app a `User` can `Post` something to his timeline and `Tag` other's users in his post (something like facebook). In my model I have to know who was tagged in which post and who did tag (always the post's owner). I've found something similar here with hashtags model, but I couldn't get the expected outcome with this.

My first question is: the approach below is right? If so, how could I validate the existence of the user before the association is created?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
    has_many :tagger_users, class_name: "Tag", foreign_key: "tagger_id"
    has_many :tagged_users, class_name: "Tag", foreign_key: "tagged_id"

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tags

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tagger_user
    belongs_to :tagged_user
    belongs_to :post
    validates_presence_of :tagger_user, :tagged_user # This always return ["Tagger post can't be blank", "Tagged post can't be blank"] even when the users are correctly set
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct thing would be having a `Tag` which belongs to two users, the tagged and the tag. Then the post can have a owner, and a list of tagged users using `has_many :through`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, :through: :tags
    belongs_to :user

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tagger_user, class_name: user
    belongs_to :tagged_user, class_name: :user

    validates_presence_of :tagger_user
    validates_presence_of :tagged_user
```

About validating check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778830/what-is-the-rails-way-of-validating-ends-of-a-many-to-many-relationship-that-mus) answer. If the ends are valid, they should be automatically persisted.